# What am I supposed to write in my if condition in order to check if there is a record in my MySQL query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What am I supposed to write in my if condition in order to check if there is a record in my MySQL query? I want to console.log('Taken') if there is already a user with the post-ed username in my user table.

```
db.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ?', [username], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if () {
      console.log('Taken');
    } else {
      console.log('Free')
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the `result` have items:

```
db.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ?', [username], function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.length) { // will test if result.lenght is > 0
        console.log('Taken');
    } else {
        console.log('Free')
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked. Would you be able to answer something else as well please? Any idea why my INSERT is not working? I console.log post and every value is inside it so I have no idea why the insert in not happening.

var post = {
          first: firstName,
          last: lastName,
          username: username,
          password: hash,
          permission: permission
      };
      
      db.query('INSERT INTO user SET = ?', post, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('ok');
      });

Comment: Sure. It's better to make other question @Bobimaru

Comment: I believe there's limit of 1 question per one and a half hours ;( .

Answer (score 0):

Try `if(result.length)`. You need to check the `result` variable for data.